# ZipFile constructor - correct way of using its mode and charset arguments

Tags: java, zip

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile-java.io.File-int-java.nio.charset.Charset-) is `ZipFile` constructor

```
 ZipFile(File file, int mode, Charset charset) throws IOException
```

How are `mode` and `charset` arguments used exactly? What are they for?

1) mode = `ZipFile.OPEN_DELETE`

When the file is deleted?

Besides this is not deleting separate files within zip-archive - why don't I just delete my zip file using `File.delete()` or `File.deleteOnExit()`?

> The file will be deleted some time between the moment that it is
>   opened and the moment that it is closed, but its contents will remain
>   accessible via the ZipFile object until either the close method is
>   invoked or the virtual machine exits.

So I delete a file like this:

```
try {

    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(new File("myZipFile.zip"), ZipFile.OPEN_DELETE);           

    // file name and comment are not read in this binary stream, do they?
    zf.getInputStream(zf.getEntry("dirInZip/fileInsideZip.txt"));
    // some operations

    zf.close(); // closes InputStream and deletes myZipFile.zip ?

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handling
}
```

2) Charset argument:

> The charset to be used to decode the ZIP entry name and comment
>   (ignored if the language encoding bit of the ZIP entry's general
>   purpose bit flag is set).

I don't understand it at all.

Before running some zip utility, file names (to be zipped) might be in non-UTF encoding (theoretically on a very old Windows it might be Windows-1252 codepage, etc), besides when I run WinZip or something I can copy-paste non-UTF text as a comment - but aren't there some standard how filenames and comment shall be stored within ZIP (I mean WinZip or such would force/change encoding to UTF-8 before zipping) ?

2.1) In which case I might expect non-UTF filenames and comment within Zip?

2.2) Using myZipFile.getEntry("dirInZip/fileInsideZip.txt") I use java String which is UTF16 inherently, so why should I ever care about encoding? I just write whatever into java String, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think 1) is clear enough: the file is deleted at some point but still accessible because loaded into memory. What's unclear about that?

Re 2), when reading a text from an external source, you need to know its encoding and use that encoding to decode the text. In reality, what you're reading is a binary stream, so need to know the method used to encode the original characters. How you then store that text (e.g. Java UTF-16) is the next step.